# ng-click in directive doesn't work in IE but works in Chrome

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm not sure if this is a known bug (or even a bug...) or not but I can't find it on the angular issues list, maybe I'm doing something wrong:

```
.directive('clickTest', function () {
    return {
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-click="click()" style="width:200px; height:200px;">Click me<div ng-transclude></div></div> Clicked {{clicked}} times',
        controller: function($scope, $element){
            $scope.clicked = 0;
            $scope.click = function() {
                $scope.clicked++;
            }
        }
    }
```

So I've essentially added the directive to an element on my page. The directive has an ng-click handler in the template and transcludes the existing elements. The ng-click runs the click() function which should trigger the click on the current scope.

In Chrome when I click the button the counter goes up by 1.

If I do the same in IE11 ***nothing happens***. I've been trying to get this working for a while as most of my target audience will be using IE

I think that this should work - as far as I can tell, angular should compile the template after transclusion to identify any further directives it needs to work with

Am I doing something wrong or should this click work?

Comment: Your code as is [works](http://jsfiddle.net/v9stcw95/) for me in IE11. Perhaps the issue lies somewhere in the code stripped out to create the posted minimal example. Or maybe the transcluded elements are interfering with the click. It might help to post your markup as well.

Comment: Ran into the same situation the OP describes if you put the `click-test` directive on a `button` element. Click event handling disparity in IE11 perhaps?

Comment: Yeah as I got into bed and was on my way off to sleep I realised it might be because I'm adding the attribute to a button element. I'll probably try wrapping it in a div and update when I realise it was just an IE quirk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knew it would be something I was doing wrong - as commenters suggested it's because I tried to add the directive to a `<button>` element.

I wrapped the element in a `<div>` instead and applied the directive to that and it works!